# YouTube API v3 - upload video using Public Access Key in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, youtube-data-api

I want to upload a file(browsed from local system) from ASP.NET Web application through YouTubeData API on behalf of user.

I have series of questions after i tried several ways and got (401) Unauthorized error.

1. Can we use Public API Access key to upload video?
2. I don't want the API to ask for user confirmation (Authorize) instead use API key to upload video at the backend. Do I want to create Public API Access Key or Server Key?
3. Whether we want to authorize Public API Access key also?
4. Is it possible to use HttpWebRequest to upload video using Public API key?

Please guide me (clear steps) which type of key i want to create and how to use the same and psuedo code to upload video using yooutube api key.

Very much useful if any one share layman example for this scenario.

**Whether anyone tried video upload using Public Key Access token?**

Thanks,
Ravi